# Why does it make a difference in the result whether I call the function "foo" or not?

Tags: c++, static

I tried running the code with and without calling the function "foo" and it yields different results. I thought because the function was empty that it wasn't going to make a difference in the result but apparently I was wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>

class Product
{
    private:
        float price;
    public:
    static float total;
    Product(float p){
      price = p;
      total+=price;
    }
    Product(Product &pr){
      price = pr.price;
      total+=price;
    }
        
};

float Product::total = 0;

void foo(Product &pr1 , Product pr2){};


int main(){
    Product p1(5.2) , p2(2.6);
  Product p3(p1);
  cout << Product::total << endl;
  foo(p1 , p2);
  cout << Product::total << endl;
}
```

The value with calling ‍‍‍`foo = 13`

The value without calling `foo = 15.6`

Comment: `Product(Product &pr){ price = pr.price; total+=price;}` -- You're not the only entity that could call the copy constructor.  It can be called in places where you don't expect it to be called, so that `total+=price;` will practically be meaningless.  Not only that, if you compile your program with different compile options, you may get different results.  Bottom line-- don't write code like this in the copy constructor of your class -- the copy constructor should have one purpose and one purpose only -- to make a copy.

Comment: Ask youself: What happens to `total` when you make a copy of a product?  Then ask: In `void foo(Product &pr1 , Product pr2)`, is `pr2` passed by value or reference and what does that mean?

Comment: pr2 in foo is a copy of p2. That adds 2.6 to the total price (according to your copy constructor). Btw, the copy constructor should take a const ref, not just a ref.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because calling `foo(p1, p2);` causes a copy of `p2` to be made, invoking the `Product` copy constructor and adding to `total`. This is because `void foo(Product&, Product)` takes its second parameter by value.